# supremum and summation Inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

I am trying to prove an Inequality
$$ \sup_{k \ge 1} \mid x_k \, \mid ^{q-p} \le \, (\mid \sum_{k \ge 1} \mid x_k \mid ^p) ^{q-p \over p} $$
where $1 \le p \le q < \infty$
How should I proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of the fact that
\begin{align*}
\sup|x_{k}|\leq\left(\sum|x_{k}|^{r}\right)^{1/r}
\end{align*}
for $r\geq 1$.

One shall note that
\begin{align*}
|x_{k}|=(|x_{k}|^{r})^{1/r}\leq\left(\sum|x_{k}|^{r}\right)^{1/r}
\end{align*}
for all $k$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarificartion. Is there a source to master a concept like this?

Comment: Any real analysis book concerning $\ell^{p}$ will do.

Comment: any recommendation

Comment: *Theory Of Measure And Integration 3rd Edition* by J. Yeh, page 439.